# How to load appsetting.json section into HashSet in .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net

```
public class AppSetting
{
   public ISet<string> B {get;set;}
}
```

//In Startup.cs

```
var appSettingsSection = Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings");
services.Configure<AppSetting>(appSettingsSection);
AppSetting appSetting = appSettingsSection.Get<AppSetting>();
```

In appsettings.json

```
{
"AppSettings":{
"B": ["One","Two","Three","Four"]
}
}
```

Current error Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.ISet`1[System.String]

Is there a way to load this data into a A and B HashSet?

Comment: Yes, it should be automatically loaded. But you should be using `HashSet<string>` as property type.

Comment: Auto, it don't understand type ISet

Comment: I want to use type HashSet, not List

Comment: Like Eldar said, try `public HashSet<string> B {get;set;}`.

Comment: It is Ok, Thank you

Comment: looks like the HashSet<string> is `null` if the json array is empty. so `"B": []` does not work, but `"B": ["One","Two","Three","Four"]` works